# Typescript generic function with generic object intersection missing type error

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

Typescript is failing to flag a type error in the following example:

```
type Base = {
  endAt?: Date;
};

const someFunction = <T extends Base>(obj: T): (Omit<T, 'endAt'> & { endAt: string }) => {
  return { ...obj, endAt: null };
};
```

I would expect an error after return, saying that null cannot be assigned to string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug, reported at [microsoft/TypeScript#42690](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42690).  When you [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) an object of [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type, the compiler approximates this as an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of the generic type with the type of the rest of the object:

```
function foo<T extends object>(t: T) {
    const bar = { ...t, a: 1, b: "" };
    /* const bar: T & { a: number; b: string; } */
    return bar;
}
```

This approximation is often sufficient, but can do undesirable things when overwriting properties:

```
const bar = foo({ a: "oops" });
/* const bar: { a: string; } & { a: number; b: string; } */
```

The inferred type of `bar` apparently has an `a` property whose type is *both* `string` *and* `number`, which is impossible.  So `bar.a` is of type `string & number` which is reduced to [the impossible `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type), and the `never` type is assignable to every type (but not vice versa):

```
function acceptBooleansOnly(x: boolean){}
acceptBooleansOnly(bar.a); // okay?!
```

Oops.

---

So this is what's happening to you.  The compiler sees the return type as `T & {endAt: null}`, which is reduced to `never` (because `null` is a *discriminant property*, and [intersections are eagerly reduced when discriminants are considered impossible](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-9.html#intersections-reduced-by-discriminant-properties)), and then `never` is assignable to any type, including `Omit<T, 'endAt'> & { endAt: string }`:

```
const someFunction = <T extends Base>(obj: T): (
  Omit<T, 'endAt'> & { endAt: string }
) => {
    type Z = T & { endAt: null }
    // type Z = never
    const z = { ...obj, endAt: null };
    // const z: never
    return { ...obj, endAt: null };
};
```

So the interaction of one reasonable but imperfect heuristic with a few other reasonable type system rules results in this weird buggy behavior.

---

Anyway, microsoft/TypeScript#42690 is on The Backlog, meaning that it's not slated to be fixed in any upcoming release.  You might want to go there and give it a  and describe why your use case is compelling, but pragmatically speaking it probably won't change much and you'll need to just be aware of it and work around it in your code, possibly by refactoring, although exactly how is out of scope for the question as asked.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?useDefineForClassFields=true&target=9&noErrorTruncation=true#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcA8AVRBTAHlbMAEwGdE4AjAK22gD4AKKALkQwEpEBvAKEX8QQEJKIgoBDAE6IAvN0QA6JVAA0icawCMaiqwBEexAF8A3HwEB6AFSDhoiZNZYAZPI2IwIALYVskk2KsIpIwYADmAUaIVhbm-JLYUCCSSA5mRjw8QmAiYlKyyKgMXOr6qAAOJIZG7GbWtjn2Uqwl7sGhEcaIrq2snj5+AbqI7eGR0bGZoJCwCOoQENjlUABCqAA22OI5APJg6wCeDLisFBtbYJwlGeILS6vn2yR7hwwOCuK1iBYW5ADW4gOmSgB3K2EQK3EJHBcl4AhwxAAglAAPysAAi4gI6TMWTsIzgXmwADFwNB4Eg5JgcPhCKQIVDsIxKFQnOxWAwdl4YFBMGoAOR05H8ujdeRClgjKAhcLGTgyUVwgQgsGIABaBRc4qRks863Wxji31+KvBGrkYGwADc-EbsrkAF4FEpKBQstQSvogfXGMzwn4NR19a22+EJJIpeSu90IojIr0+0w8UxAA)

Comment: This makes sense for the example in my post, however this bug is still present if the return is `T & {endAt: Date}`. Since `Date & (Date | undefined)` is `Date`, why would there still be no error?

Comment: If what "return" is `T & {endAt: Date}`?  Can you show me with code?

Comment: [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictPropertyInitialization=false#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFNoG8BQ0PQQOwCYEEAXAfgC5oARMQhVAX1VWAHtsJDoJmBbBAMQCu2YIQCWraAF5oAHgAqWAB408MeBAQA+ABTMARgCtycgJTkA8t1GF5AGmgByHAUIPN0AGQoseIuSo00HRS7miY0ABOCIQCEdgoAHRJ+gb2zn7Q2AIgIAx0ANxAA)

Comment: For the same reason `acceptsBooleansOnly(bar.a)` works in my answer; the intersection is reduced to `never`, and `never` is a subtype of every single type.  [This](https://tsplay.dev/mq95km) also has no error.  Does that make sense now?

Comment: Oh, so the reduction to never is happening in the spread itself, irrespective of the return type in the signature of the function. If so, that makes sense. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, you got it.  It's annoying because each piece is somewhat reasonable but when it's put together it's clearly not desirable.

Comment: That is annoying. Can you suggest a way of rewriting this function to provide type safety in this scenario?

Comment: You could perform an explicit destructuring to get a compiler-inferred `Omit` like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w25azW), for example.  There might be lots of other workarounds but a comment section isn't a great place to explore those.